# Compound vision system or Megapixel camera reduction

Tags: computer-vision

Are any commercially available compound vision sensors available?
Not a simple 8 sensor system using photo-diodes but a genuine sensor that can provide a >32x32 compound matrix. Would some form of reduction in the granularity of a megapixel camera be a better option? The real purpose is to reduce processing time to a minimum, while extracting the maximum basic information.

Comment: Is there a problem with simply using a regular camera and resizing the image down to 32×32 pixels?

Comment: @Ian; I was looking for a compound vision sensor, but did ask if a reduction in a standard camera resolution would be better

Comment: I'm asking if there's a specific reason why you wouldn't want to use the camera, since you seem to be having trouble finding the exact vision sensor you want.

Comment: @Ian; I would have liked to try a compound camera to enable some bio-emulation/understanding, but I will be using a camera (possibly limiting the number of pixels processed or merging blocks of pixels).Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The following people have used a compound eye for the development of their insect inspired rotor craft to demonstrate panoramic optical flow methods without the use of accelerometers.

[**Flying over uneven moving terrain based on optic-flow cues without
any need for reference frames or accelerometers**](http://iopscience.iop.org/1748-3190/10/2/026003/pdf/1748-3190_10_2_026003.pdf)

The sensors are described here; [**Curvace**](http://www.curvace.org/)

Paper here; [**Miniature curved artificial compound eyes**](http://www.pnas.org/content/110/23/9267)

Video here; https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=xKi5wSpslPE

With a detailed description of the fabrication here;
[**Supporting Information**](http://www.pnas.org/content/suppl/2013/05/17/1219068110.DCSupplemental/pnas.201219068SI.pdf)